# Is there a way to prevent Sublime Text from previewing binary files inside the text editor?

Tags: sublimetext2

As the title suggests, I would like to find out if there's a way to prevent ST2 from opening binary files when I click on them. For example when I click on an image, there's no point displaying the hex representation inside the text editor.

One additional note: I'm not interested in hiding binary files from the sidebar.

Answer (score 53):

Files containing null bytes are opened as hexadecimal by default
In your User or Default Settings file:

```
"enable_hexadecimal_encoding": false
```

Comment: This was really useful!

Comment: this setting prevent sublime to convert binaries to hexadecimal and make binaries opening quicker. But it does not prevent it to open them

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately I'm not aware of a way to disabled previewing of specific formats, but if you want to avoid accidental clicks on enormous binary files that may slow down the editor you could disable all previewing from sidebar clicks.

In your User or Default Settings file(s):

```
"preview_on_click": false
```

Answer (score 8):

I have  similar situation like you. I dont want sublime open editor for binary like jpg png files. Instead open system default application is more reasonable.

1. **Create one Build**. Refer to [Sublime Text 2 keyboard shortcut to open file in specified browser (e.g. Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023879/sublime-text-2-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-file-in-specified-browser-e-g-chrome)   It will both open default application and hex editor.
2. **Plugin OpenDefaultApplication**   https://github.com/SublimeText/OpenDefaultApplication
   It will have context right click menu OpenInDefaultApplication.  But It will both open default application and hex editor as well
3. **Plugin: Non Text Files**   https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Non%20Text%20Files   Add config in the user setting

   ```
   "binary_file_patterns": ["*.JPG","*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"],
   "prevent_bin_preview": true,
   "open_externally_patterns": [
      "*.JPG",
      "*.jpg",
      "*.jpeg",
      "*.JPEG",
      "*.png",
       "*.PGN",
      "*.gif",
       "*.GIF",
       "*.zip",
       "*.ZIP",
       "*.pdf",
       "*.PDF"
   ]
   ```

I choose the third way, it's quite suitable for me. It will open jpg file in system default application and quickly close the edit mode automatically.

Comment: The `image` formats are supported out of the box since ST3

Comment: Also `prevent_bin_preview` is now `preview_on_click` for ST3

Answer (score 0):

## For Sublime Text 3

### `file_exclude_patterns` Setting

If your binary files have a file extension, then yes.

In your Sublime Settings you can use this setting to prevent you from seeing the files in the left project folders:

```
"file_exclude_patterns":
[
    "*.db",
    "*.dll",
    "*.ds_store",
    "*.egg",
    "*.enc",
    "*.eot",
    "*.exe",
    "*.ko",
    "*.otf",
    "*.pdb",
    "*.pdf",
    "*.pgn",
    "*.plist",
    "*.psd",
    "*.pxm",
    "*.pyc",
    "*.rdb",
    "*.sqlite",
    "*.sublime-workspace",
    "*.ttf",
    "*.woff",
    "*.woff2",
    "*.zip",
],
```

Just modify this to your needs, and then you will not see this in your project folders in Sublime.

### Toggle

Maybe you just want to turn it off or on for the current file?

Try `Sublime Command Palette` using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> OR <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

and type:

```
HexViewer: Toggle Hex View
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>  then the file will switch between `HEX` and `TEXT`.

### Extra

If you don't want any-file to be converted to HEX then please use [@steven-teo's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25321719/1896134)

If you want to learn more about the HEX Viewer you can see the [Code Here](https://github.com/facelessuser/HexViewer) & [Documentation Here.](http://facelessuser.github.io/HexViewer/#overview)

**Note: Keys vary for the `Sublime Command Palette` [more info on that.](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/usage)