# Package Control - plugin to run file in browser

Tags: sublimetext2

I am looking plugin to run .html file in browser and also open folder in windows explorer.

The reason is simply. I always start work in the same way: run Sublime Text 2, click 16 times with mouse on folder to open folder with project and run index.html or other. I also need open folder because i copy there from time to time some graphics or other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Navigating to files**
You can save your workspace as a project in Sublime Text so you don't have to re-navigate to the same files every time.

- Open the files you need and lay them out however you like
- Go to Project > Save Project As and save the project file somewhere convenient
- Open the project file to resume work on those files

As a side note, I highly recommend the [SyncedSidebar](https://github.com/sobstel/SyncedSideBar) plugin to automatically expand the sidebar to reveal the files you have open.

You *should* also be able to right click in the file you're editing and "Reveal in Windows Explorer" (I use a Mac so I can only verify "Reveal in Finder").

**Opening in a browser**
You can set up a [build path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8023999/1684247) for this, or use a plugin like [View in Browser](https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser).